# How to determine if an element in a C array has yet to be assigned to anything?

Tags: c, arrays, null

So as I understand when initialising an "empty" array in C (as shown below), you are initialising each element to 0 (since C does not have a null value).

```
int values[5] = {0}; // each element has a value of 0
```

However, if I assign a few random values to my int array as shown below...

```
// examples for assigned values, but they can be from all over the range
values[0] = 1;
values[1] = 0;
values[2] = -1;
```

How would I check which elements in my array have yet to have a value assigned to it?

I.e. what is the best way to approach the following?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // find out whether this element was already assigned a specific value
    if (array[i] == ??? )
    {
        // the element has yet to be assigned
    }
}
```

Comment: The short answer is: You can't. Unless you keep track of which elements you assign to some other (manual and explicit) way. There is also no way to check if an element (or a variable in general) have been initialized or not.

Comment: `int values[5] = {};` is not valid syntax.

Comment: Are the -1, 0, 1 the only values which could be assigned to the array elements? Or could the assigned values cover all of the range of the chosen data type?

Comment: I tried to keep the question general so the values are not limited to -1, 0 and 1 and can in fact cover all of the range of the chosen data type. However, I believe @Stephan Lechner  's solution is great in instances where the values do not cover the entire range of the chosen data type.

Comment: In addition to Stephan Lechner's answer, you can use code generation to have the compiler initialize an array at compile time rather than at execution time, if a compiler can handle the size of your array. That way, you can have `int array[] = { UNDEFINED_VALUE, UNDEFINED_VALUE, ..., UNDEFINED_VALUE };`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach for the more difficult situation that the possible values assigned explicitly to the array elements cover all of the range of the used data type (otherwise see other answer, i.e. init the whole array to an unused value):

You should make another array of the same size, initialise it completely with values which indicate "not yet initialised".
Then, whenever you initialise an array element of the original array, write a value which indicates "already initialised" to the second array, at the same index.
That way the question "has this entry been initialised?" can be answered by looking at the same index in the second array.

However, initialising an array can be done with

```
int values[5] = {0};
```

Thils will initialise the first entry with the given "0" and all the rest implicitly with "0" as default value (which is not related to the given zero).
Then the answer to "initialised?" is always "yes".
(I see you already picked up the correct array initialisation from comments. I keep this answer part for clarity about the meaning of the single value used.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, seems like this is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

For scalar data types as `int`, C indeed does not have a commonly accepted / defined value for "undefined"; it's rather subject to the individual code if one *interprets* a specific value in the range of `int` as "undefined".

Usually you will define such a value with something that is out of the "practical" range for your use-case; For example, if the values denote an index of an array, one could write `#define UNDEF_INDEX UINT_MAX`, because it is unlikely that an array will get such a size. For int, you could say `#define UNDEFINED_VALUE INT_MIN`.

```
#define UNDEFINED_VALUE INT_MIN

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   array[i] = UNDEFINED_VALUE;
}

...

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (array[i] == UNDEFINED_VALUE )
    {
        // the element has yet to be assigned
    }
}
```